# How do I delete the first year of data by variable from a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with various stock symbols and prices by day, and I'm looking to remove the first year of data for each symbol.

Current dataframe:

```
    Date                   Symbol  Price
    2009-01-01 00:00:00    A       $10.00
    2009-01-02 00:00:00    A       $11.00
    ...
    2010-01-01 00:00:00    A       $12.00
    ...
    2019-01-01 00:00:00    A       $15.00
    2009-01-01 00:00:00    B       $100.00
    ...
    2019-01-01 00:00:00    B       $200.00
```

Goal dataframe:

```
    Date                  Symbol  Price
    2010-01-01 00:00:00    A       $12.00
    ...
    2019-01-01 00:00:00    A       $15.00
    2010-01-01 00:00:00    B       $100.00
    ...
    2019-01-01 00:00:00    B       $200.00
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You need to repeat your tutorials on Pandas.  Look for the `drop` and `filter` methods.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Please, show some effort and your solutions that you tried.

Comment: you can use column `Data` to get only year and then you can use it to drop rows. If `Date` is as string then you could try `df[ df["Date"].str[:4] != "2009" ]` to get rows without `2009`. But if it keeps date as `datetime` object then you may need something like `df[ df["Date"].dt.year != 2009 ]` but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

You can use column `Data` to get only year and then you can use it to drop rows.

If `Date` is as string then you could try to get year using

```
df["Year"] = df["Date"].str[:4]
```

and filter using string `"2009"`

```
df = df[ df["Year"] != "2009" ]
```

If it keeps `Date` as `datetime` object then you may need something like

```
df["Year"] = df["Date"].dt.year
```

and filter using integer `2009`

```
df = df[ df["Year"] != 2009 ]
```

but I'm not sure.